# Error: [firestore/unknown] java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am adding this minimal code for which I am receiving this error

```
firestore()
  .collection('someCollection')
  .doc('someDocument')
  .set({
    test: 5,
  })
  .catch(e => {
    alert(e);
  });
```

Version of firestore:
**"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.7.0",**

I am not getting any error when I use {test : 'something'} for the document.

Why is this happening ? I want to store integer value in the test

Answer (score 0):

[look at breaking changes for v14](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1400-2021-12-14)
You need check your 'where/in' clauses.

Probably, previously you may had like this
`.where('time' > user.registerTime.toDate().getTime())`
but now it throws exception.

To make it tmp working you can write like this
`.where('time' > ${user.registerTime.toDate().getTime()})`
It will not throw exception but idk is this correct way or not

(probably, the best solution is performing migration on firestore server side, as they mentioned to get rid of this ugly tmp fix)